# Hide CSS class with Javascript in the afternoon each day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, time, hide

I am hoping to hide a css class or ID with Javascript between some hours of the day. It is for a menu, so let's say after 12pm, the menu disappears, each day and appears at maybe 8am.

I've tried searching both here and various other places but I'm unable to find a solution. Perhaps because when you search for "javascript" and "time" or "hours" it comes up with results about removing after an amount of time the item is on the page when it loads for a user. Obviously that is not what I am after here.

[Here is what I am trying](http://jsfiddle.net/ft8hz5uf/5):

```
var H = new Date();
document.getElementById("hour").innerHTML = H.getHours();
var M = new Date();
document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML = M.getMinutes();
```

Finished JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ft8hz5uf/6/

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried searching for how to get the time and just hiding elements after a time examples:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

timeout: http://jsfiddle.net/MMsML/

or this kind of thing:
`setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mydiv').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000); // <-- time in milliseconds`

However, I'm not sure how to get either jQ or JS to find the time then hide the class based on what the time is. I assume i'll have to set a variable?

Comment: anyway, the answers you got here should solve your problem

Comment: @TheMysticalSock Then please **[edit]** the question and add what you've tried. If you don't tell us, [we can't guess](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt). Please take some time to read the [help/on-topic], the [ask] page and how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Hugo please see changes :)

Though the downvote was not needed because I was asking where to start. Not for you to do the work for me...

Though with my addition of my jsfiddle, improvements are welcome.

Comment: If you're not asking for code or "do work for me", then write the question in a way that doesn't give this impression (and when you don't provide your code, lots of people have this impression).

Comment: great answer from Ozan, holden's code also gave me a great place to start.

I changed the code to do what I needed and added repeats for other DIVs.

FInal code here, thanks to all.

http://jsfiddle.net/ft8hz5uf/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) method of `date object`.

```js
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
if (hour > 12) {
  //12 to 23:59:59
  $("#before-noon").hide();
  $("#after-noon").show();
} else {
  //00 to 11:59:59
  $("#before-noon").show();
  $("#after-noon").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="before-noon">Before Noon</div>
<div id="after-noon">After Noon</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, here is my final code. Thanks! jsfiddle.net/ft8hz5uf/6/

 (sorry, I can't upvote)

Answer (score 2):

A basic approach might be:

```
var hours = new Date().getHours();
if (hours >= 13 && hours <= 19) {
   [do something]
} else {
    [do something else]
}
```

It shouldn't be necessary to remind that hours, in this case, are relative to user time (so the browser will show different thing if in Australia rather than in Europe...)
If you are looking for an absolute time, regardeless the user's time, you should use a server-side approuch.

Comment: as orders will just be in the UK I think it should be fine, but yes, good point. I will probably use UTC

Answer (score 1):

you must do a function that takes the current time and validates if it is within the parameter you want. this should hide or show the class

```
 function validateTime() {
    const currentHour = new Date().getHours(); // hours from 0 to 23
    if(currentHour > 8  && currentHour < 18){ // true for the hours between 8am and 6pm
        //logic for add class
        $(query).addClass('class');
    } else {
        // logic for remove class
        $(query).removeClass('class');
    }
}

// you can make the function run every minute

setInterval(validateTime, 1000*60);
```

Comment: does AddClass simply add a class to an object, or does it show it if it was previously hidden?